# C# Inheritance Discussion from MTA

Tags: c#, inheritance, mta

A question on a C# MTA exam I've done recently that has caused a large amount of discussion:

You have a class named Glass that inherits from a base class named Window. The Window class includes a protected method named break().

How should you call the Glass class implementation of the break() method?

A.  Window.break();

B.  Glass.break();

C.  this.break();

D.  base.break();

Can anyone give me a solid answer and rational for this?

Comment: that depends whether the `break()` method is overridden on `glass` class or not

Comment: worth reading up about the protected keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by simply calling `Break();`, As long as the `Break()` method is not declared as `virtual` (which makes it possible to override it). Calling using `this` or `base` is simply redundant.

However let´s say that `Break()` would be declared virtual then it would be the matter if you would want to call the implementation of `Break()` on the Window class (`base.Break()`) or on the Glass class (`Break()`/`this.Break()`).

Consider the following code

```
public class Window
{
    public virtual void Break()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Break in window called");
    }
}

public class Glass : Window
{
    public override void Break()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Break in Glass called");
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Break();
        this.Break(); // Same as above line
        base.Break();
    }
}
```

The output when calling `DoSomething()` on an instance of `Glass` would be

```
Break in Glass called
Break in Glass called
Break in window called
```

Comment: This was my thinking too, but others weren't so sure (Including the lecturer, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**

How should you call the Glass class implementation of the break() method?

> **Example**

In this example they have an class named `Glass`. This class has a method called `Break()` that comes from the base class `Window`.

They want you to call the implemented method in the `Glass class` *"call the Glass class implementation of the break() method"*

To create an own version of a base class method you need to make it over writable. To do this add virtual to the base class method and in the derived class `Glass` add override to override that base class method.]

Next you can call different version of the method the derived method and base method. See Example for more details

This example will look like this:

```
 class Window
 {
     public virtual void Break()
     {
           // break method from the window class 
     }
 }

 class Glass : Window
 {
     public override void Break()
     {
           // This method comes from the base class Window. You want to override this one. They ask you to call this method.

           //To call the Break() mehod from Window:
           base.Break();
           // Call the Break() method from the current instance
           this.Break()
           Break(); 
     }
 }
```

> **Answer:**

This answer is right because this one calls the current instance off the `Glass class Break() method` (See example)

C: this.break();

> **Other answers:**

The `Break()` is not static because that would not make any sense and can't be made static in this question.  They want a Glass to inherit from Window and want to call the `Break()` version of the Glass class.  You need to override the `Break()` in the Glass class to create an own version of that method, Because of that you need to add virtual and override and  virtual/override methods can not be made static. Because of that the first two answers are incorrect

**A Window.Break()**

This will call the static Break() Method from the Window class.  (static is not used in this example this is not the answer)

**B Glass.Break()**

This will call the static Break() Method from the class. (static is not used in this example this is not the anwer)

**C this.Break()**

This will call the current instance Break() Method (See Example).

**D base.Break()**

This will call the Break() method from the current instance of base class Window.

Comment: To me the use of the form Glass and not glass implied a static method, not a mistyping of an object named glass, but perhaps they're not as pedantic as I'd hope on a software Development MTA

Comment: The `Break()` is not static because that would not make any sense and can't be made static in this question.  They want a `Glass` to inherit from Window and want to call the `Break()` version of the `Glass class`.  You need to override the `Break()` in the `Glass class` to create an own version of that method, Because of that you need to add virtual and override and  virtual/override methods can not be made static.

Comment: I'm certainly aware of that,  but your first answer was "B: Glass .Break()". You've altered it since then, quickly, so it doesn't appear in the edits - my comment was referring to that.

Comment: Aaaw I get it, It is right it was my first answer but I read the question again and I noticed that I was wrong and changed my answer to the right answer XD.

Answer (score -1):

**B. Glass.break();**

It is not specified in task from where it's called, so since there should be only 1 correct solution, only logical way would be to assume it can be called from anywhere. So if we implement **break()** as a *public static* method we'll be able to call it from anywhere and **B** would be the only logical and possible answer.

```
using System;
public class Window{
    protected void break1() {Console.Write("1");}
    public Window(){
        Glass.break1();
    }
}
public class Glass : Window{
    public static void break1() {Console.Write("2");}
    public Glass() {
        Glass.break1();
    }
}
public class Dijete : Glass{
    public Dijete() {
        Glass.break1();
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Glass.break1();
    }
}
```

Please correct my logic if I'm wrong, but on exam dumps I also found B as correct answer.

PS: I called it break1, because calling it break() won't work, which actually makes this whole task make no sense.